# Selecting a Chart/Graph in Excel with AutoHotKey

Tags: excel, autohotkey

Currently I am able to select cell ranges with AutoHotKey, however I am wanting to select an actual Chart/Graph that I have inserted into my excel workbook. My question is how do I select the chart itself and not just a cell range? any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I have tried oworkBook.ActiveSheet.Range ("Chart") .Activate. this does not seem to be working.

Comment: oworkBook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Your Chart Name").Copy this seems to work and copy the chart like I want it too.